# How to verify the values from a multi value dictionary against each key in node.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I have following dictionary with multiple values and while iterating through the loop, i need to verify any of those values are equal to the url respectively.

```
console.log("Hello World")


const dns =require('dns')

//Verify the status of the url

function verify_URL(url_list){

    for(url in url_list) {

         dns.lookup(url, function(err, result){

            if (result == url_list[url][0]){

                console.log("Url equal to 1",url, url_list[url][0] );

            }
              else if(result == url_list[url][1]){
                console.log("Url equal to 2", url, url_list[url][1]);


              }
              else {
                  console.log("Url is not accesable and server is down", url)

              }

         })


        }
}

var dic = {'facebook.com':["157.240.25.35","157.240.25.36"],'google.com': ["172.217.160.142","172.217.160.143"]}

verify_URL(dic)
```

Expected:
I need to get the result for each url one by one, here in the case, it could be as follows

Url equal to 1 facebook.com 157.240.25.35
Url equal to 1 google.com 172.217.160.142

Actual;
In the result iam getting following value

Url equal to 1 google.com 172.217.160.142
Url is not accesable and server is down google.com

Appreciate if anyone can help on this?

Thank you

Comment: Your code just works fine. What's the problem? It outputs `ip1, server1`, which seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi @Alireza, I actually need to get all value one by one against each key's url:["ip1","ip2"] as follows,

value = "ip1" then value ="ip2" for the key url . 

Simlarly for the key url1.

 Appreciate if you can help?

Comment: please add the expected results in complete form to avoid misunderstandings and I'll be happy to help.

Comment: Hi @Alireza As suggested, i have edited the above question with the full code and mentioned what iam looking for. Please look in to this and let me know if can help on this 
Thank You

Comment: Hi @Alireza Any help that you can give me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `let` keyword in your `for...in` loop.

```js
console.log("Hello World")


const dns =require('dns')

//Verify the status of the url

function verify_URL(url_list){

    for(let url in url_list) {

         dns.lookup(url, function(err, result){

            if (result == url_list[url][0]){

                console.log("Url equal to 1",url, url_list[url][0] );

            }
              else if(result == url_list[url][1]){
                console.log("Url equal to 2", url, url_list[url][1]);


              }
              else {
                  console.log("Url is not accesable and server is down", url)

              }

         })


        }
}

var dic = {'facebook.com':["157.240.25.35","157.240.25.36"],'google.com': ["172.217.160.142","172.217.160.143"]}

verify_URL(dic)
```

In addition, please note that your current algorithm of checking the returned dns lookup against two IPs will probably fail in most cases, because facebook and google have many more IPs and chances are high that the specific IP that you receive is not in your current list.

What you could do is to create an array with many more IPs for each domain and loop over it to check the result against it, instead of statically checking the first and second element.

Comment: Would appreciate if you could upvote and accept the answer if it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Really clean and simple with destructuring:

```
var [value] = dict[key];
console.log(value);
```

Unless all you need is an array of the first item in each array, in which case you'd do this:

```
const firstItems = Object.values(dict).map(([e]) => e);
```

<sub>(It'll be unordered though, because that's how JavaScript objects work.)</sub>

Comment: Hi @Jack, Thank you for your answer, however, its giving the first value as expected, but how to get the second value as "ip2" ? I actually need to get all value one by one against each key's


url:["ip1","ip2"]


value = "ip1"  
then 
value ="ip2" for the key url .   Simlarly for the key url1 

Appreciate if you can help?